# C++11 compilation error when specifying lambda capture

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, clang, llvm

Let this code tell the story (or watch the [showterm](http://showterm.io/3bf242b5ea41a223dd439#fast)):

```
#include <iostream>

int foo(bool func (void)) {
  int i; for (i = 0; i < 10 && func(); i++);
  return i;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << foo([] {
    return true;
  }) << std::endl;

  bool a = false;
  std::cout << foo([&a] { // error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
    return a = !a;
  }) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I expect to be able to capture `a` within my lambda, and be able to alternate the return value.
My actual case has much more involved, but it boils down to that. I'd like to be able to use lambdas, though the alternative would be using a plain function with a global variable to hold the state.

I'm compiling with:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 testcase.cc
```

I'm using Apple's LLVM:

```
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can convert lambda to function pointer (`bool func (void)`) if and only if it does not capture anything. So first part compiles but second part won't.

You should use `std::function`

```
#include <functional>

int foo(std::function<bool(void)> func) {
  int i; for (i = 0; i < 10 && func(); i++);
  return i;
}
```

or template

```
template <class TFunc>
int foo(TFunc && func) {
  int i; for (i = 0; i < 10 && func(); i++);
  return i;
}
```

Comment: That was it. I don't know how I didn't find the original question.

Comment: You'll want to take `func` by value, "universal reference," or const reference; the result of evaluating a lambda expression is a prvalue, so `TFunc &` won't work.